# R shiny radio button

Tags: r, shiny

I a new to R shiny and building an application in R shiny. I want to present a table with two different outputs based on the out1 variable. For that, I wrote

```
output$inputs <- renderDataTable({
    if((input$O1 == 'Max_profit'))
    inpts()
  })
  output$inputs <- renderDataTable({
    if (( inputs$O1 == 'Optimum_profit'))
    inpts1()
  })
```

When I press the action button in UI,  I cannot see any output in UI. It is showing object inputs not found.

I searched the internet but could not find anything. Please, help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 divs with the same name. You either rename them, or wrap your `if` statement into a reactive or take all the conditions into one expression:

```
output$inputs <- renderDataTable({
        if(is.null(nput$O1)){
                return()
        }
        if(input$O1 == 'Max_profit'){
                inpts()
        }
        if(inputs$O1 == 'Optimum_profit'){
                inpts1()
        }
})
```