# Filter columns based on radio button selection in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, reactive

Hi I've been working on a small project on English premier league. I want to create a reactive table based on radio button selection. My sample table is of the form (data is fictional),

```
Team         G_Played H_goals A_goals H_wins A_wins H_loss A_loss
Arsenal        200      120     87      35     20     45     30
Aston Villa    200      118     74      26     14     98     75
Chelsea        200      147     98      48     30     25     28
Bolton         200      108     84      26     14     57     60
```

If I select "Home" on my radio button, I want records only from Team, G_played, H_goals, H_wins, H_loss. Similarly if I select "Away" I should be able to get Team, G_played, A_goals, A_wins, A_loss.

I've tried the solution from this example, [R shiny radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436356/r-shiny-radio-button).  But I don't know how to call multiple columns for given radio button selection.

Can someone please suggest a code or suggest what I can start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build an if condition to transform your dataset. You can make this in a reactive function like it is recommanded to do in a shiny app, or directly in your output function.

`if(input$radiobutton == 'Home'){ df <- df %>% select(G_played, H_goals, ....) }`

Same if `'Away'`